# Is there a ritual in Hinduism when son leaves parents house?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, rituals, initiation, men

I'm just wondering, is there a ritual in Hinduism, where a son leaves the house of the parents if he is going to live in his own house alone?

Comment: it's usually called "marriage" nowadays :). in olden days, sons would stay with their parents even after marriage.

Comment: There is no such ritual. There can be peronsal "duties" like job, etc. If a new house is made though - *graha-pravesh* ceremony will be done

Comment: **Also**, Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.